# Using Meld toghter with TFS 2010

Tags: version-control, tfs, meld

I'm testing different 3-way merge tools for TFS 2010.
Does anybody have the command line parameter setup for [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/).

I'm looking for something like [that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

After some research and because I found no answer to this question, I've started trying to build the command myself, based on [this blog](http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2012/09/three-way-git-merging-with-meld.html).

In VS 2010, to access command configuration go to: `Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server` and then select `Configure User Tools...`

---

**Operation: Compare**

Extension: `.*`

Command (this is meld.exe file path): `"D:\Software\Meld\meld\meld.exe"`

Arguments (this means that you want to compare server file to your modified file): `%1 %2`

---

**Operation: Merge**

This was not easy to figure it out. We can do by other ways, but I think this one is good (it works at least)!

First, we need to create a *bat file* that we'll call `meld_start.bat`.
Then we put the following commands inside the bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF

COPY /Y NUL %4

START /WAIT /D "D:\Software\Meld\meld" meld.exe --auto-merge %1 %2 %3 -o %4 --diff %2 %1 --diff %2 %3
```

The tricky line is `START /WAIT /D "D:\Software\Meld\meld" meld.exe --auto-merge %1 %2 %3 -o %4 --diff %2 %1 --diff %2 %3`. The command means that we'll start meld with the following parameters:

`meld.exe %1 %2 %3 -o %4` - This means that ou want to compare file %1, %2 and %3 (%2 is the base) and set the merged output inside file %4

`--diff %2 %1 --diff %2 %3` - This means that you want to open another two tabs with two comparisons: base file with the server and base file with our file >>> this is optional. if we don´t want we can remove this from bat file.

**In VS 2010 we configure Merge command like this:**

Extension: `.*`

Command (this is meld_start.bat file path): `"D:\Software\Meld\meld\meld_start.bat"`

Arguments (this means that you want to merge your file, base file and server file. The merged content will be stored on %4 file): `%2 %3 %1 %4`

I hope this can help some one!

Comment: My last comment refers to stable version **Meld 1.8.5**.

Comment: This trick still works for **Meld 3.16.2 - 6 August 2016** :-)

Answer (score 1):

Refering to development version of **[Meld 3.11.1](http://ftp.gnome.org/Public/GNOME/binaries/win32/meld/3.11/)** the steps are the same, but there are a few things we need to do, if we want to get syntax highlighting and latin1 file comparisons:

- To Allow read "latin1" encoded files, we need to substitute **gschemas.compiled** file in **[Install Dir]\share\meld** folder by another one compiled with latin1 option, like this:

Locate your PyGObjectWin32 install folder (probably C:\Python27\Libs\site-packages\gnome) and find **glib-compile-schemas** within it.

Run **glib-compile-schemas** on the data folder [**source code folder \data\org.gnome.meld.gschema.xml**] to generate gschemas.compiled, after changing *org.gnome.meld.gschema.xml* file.

- To get **syntax highlighting** we need to locate **gtksourceview-3.0** folder and copy it into **[Install Dir]\share** folder